# Change label text when select a date from J Query date-picker

Tags: c#, jquery, c#-4.0, code-behind, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following function that take the date picked using J Query date-picker and call code behind function in C#

```
<script>
     $(function () {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                monthNames: ["كانون الثاني", "شباط", "آذار", "نيسان", "أيار", "حزيران", "تموز", "آب", "أيلول", "تشرين الأول", "تشرين الثاني", "كانون الأول"],
                dayNames: ["أحد", "اثنين", "ثلاثاء", "أربعاء", "خميس", "جمعة", "سبت"],
                dayNamesMin: ["أحد", "اثنين", "ثلاثاء", "أربعاء", "خميس", "جمعة", "سبت"] ,
                firstDay: 0,
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    alert(date);
                    PageMethods.changeDate(date);
                }   
            }
           );
     });
</script>
```

and this is the code behind method

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static void changeDate(string date)
    {
        //Session["date"] = date;

        //lblCurrentDate.text = date;
    }
```

i want to change the text of label and put "date" on the session,
but this is not work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform a server call in your javascript code.
You have to perform an ajax call to the server PageMethod instead.

Take a look at **$.ajax()**.

[Here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) is a good example.